# Different digital signature for the same message when Java webservice deployed on different operating systems that run the same application server

Tags: java, xml, web-services, operating-system, digital-signature

I am programming a webservice that requires a digital signature for the sent and received XML messages, which is programmed in JAVA using bouncycastle library for signing the sent messages and verifying the received ones. The Webservice is deployed on Weblogic application server. I noticed that the same exact message produces different signature when the webservice is deployed on a Windows server than when deployed on a Linux server.

I have tried deploying the same exact code on different machines that has Weblogic application server and the ones that are running on Windows produce the same signature while the ones running on Linux produce another one. The entity that is going to consume the webservice successfully verified the signature from the messages that are produced on the windows server but weren't able to do the same for the ones produced on the Linux server (they use Windows as an operating system on their servers).

Both the private key and the certificate used in signing and verifying the digital signatures are read from files using FileInputStream. To make sure the problem is not with the certificates I  tried reading the certificates from a hard coded String inside the code and the same problem happens. I also wrote a simple webservice that verifies the signature that I produce, the ones produced on Windows are successfully verified on the verifier deployed on windows while the ones produced on Linux aren't and vice-versa.

Taking into notice that the XML messages are reformatted before the signing process (all white spaces are removed and then the XML gets reformatted), is there any suggestions or ideas about the reason for this as I am running out of ideas? Does it have any thing to do with the character encoding or the way line feed and carriage return are handled in different operating systems?

Thanks.

Edit: Here is a simplified code for the signing process that follows the same logic that I used in my original code, the imports are not added and no exception handling in this code and most of the functions has been in-lined to make it simpler, also the class "Utils" that is used in the XML formatting process is not provided for the sake of simplicity but there is a description written beside each call for a function from that class, I will provide that class and the original code if needed:

```
public class Initializer {
    private static Signer signer = null; // a reference to the class that will do the signing process
    private static XPathExpression mssgBody;
    private static XPathExpression signatureNodePath;

    static {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
            KeyStore keystore;

            keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");

            keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/home/path/path/MyKeyPair.p12"), "123".toCharArray()); //loading My keypair to a keystore (only the private key will be used) 

            Key key = keystore.getKey("CertificateAlias", "Password".toCharArray());

            java.security.cert.Certificate cert;
            cert = keystore.getCertificate("CertificateAlias");
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)key;

            signer = new Signer(privateKey, "UTF-16LE", "SHA256withRSA"); //Creating a new Signer object and providing the private key and the message encoding and the signature algorithm
            mssgBody = Utils.compileExpression(null, "//MsgBody", null); //  set the  path for the message body that will be signed
            signatureNodePath = Utils.compileExpression(null, "//Signature", null); // set the path for the signature node where the signature will be put

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        }
    }

    public static String sign(Node request) throws XPathExpressionException, Exception { //the function that will be called by the web service
        String mssgBodyString = Utils.convertNode2String(Utils.extractNodeList(request, mssgBody).item(0)); // Extract the message body and convert it into a String
        mssgBodyString = Utils.getFromattedXML(mssgBodyString); //format the string containing XML data, each new opening or closing tag will be on a new line and each new nested tag will be indented by two spaces
        String signature = signer.sign(mssgBodyString); // Return signature

        return signature;
    }
}

public class Signer{

    private KeyStore signKeyStore;

    private PrivateKey privateKey;

    /** Final Instances **/
    private String MSG_ENCODER;
    private String SIGNATURE_ALG;

    public Signer(PrivateKey prk, String msgEncoder, String signatureAlg) {

        privateKey = prk;
        MSG_ENCODER = msgEncoder; //"UTF-16LE"
        SIGNATURE_ALG = signatureAlg; //"SHA256withRSA"
    }

        /******************* Signing process ************************/

    public String sign(final String msg) throws Exception {  // the function that will be called form the initializer class
        return sign(msg, SIGNATURE_ALG, MSG_ENCODER);
    }


    /**
     * @param msgStr: String for which digital signature will be calculated
     * @param signatureAlg: Name of requested Signature Algorithm
     * @param msgEncoder: Encoder used encoding the input message to bytes array
     * @param sigEncoder: Type of byte encoder  (Hex, Base64, ...)
     *
     * @return strSignature: String Formatted Signature for passed string data, based on passed encoder
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String sign(final String msgStr, final String signatureAlg, final String msgEncoder) throws Exception {

        byte[] signature;
        String strSignature = "";
        signature = this.sign(msgStr.getBytes(msgEncoder));

        // encode the result signature based on the specified encoder
        strSignature = encode(signature);

        return strSignature;
    }

    public byte[] sign(final byte[] data) throws Exception {

        Signature signer;
        byte[] signature = null;


        try {

            signer = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALG, new BouncyCastleProvider());

            signer.initSign(privateKey); // calling initSign from java.security Package
            signer.update(data, 0, data.length);
            signature = signer.sign();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Message Signing failed; ", e);
        }

        return signature;
    }

     /*** encoding / decoding****/

    /**
     * encodes byte array into String using Base64
     * @param bytes
     * @return  encoded String
     */
    private String encode(byte[] bytes) {
        return new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
    }

    /**
     * Decode String using Base64
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    private byte[] decode(String str) {
        return Base64.decode(str);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample files.

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is that you're signing a String instead of a `byte[]`. Ideally, you would use some API which is able to sign an XML Node directly so you don't have this problem. I'm using openSAML for Java, I think it can be used for C# as well.

Comment: Hello @Davio, the String is converted to byte[] in the following code line:    signature = this.sign(msgStr.getBytes(msgEncoder));  ... do you mean that the message shouldn't be converted to String at all in any stage of the signing process?

Comment: No, preferably not. Well, it happens at some point eventually, but I'm using a library which is able to sign XML elements, have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am using BouncyCastle library for the signing process, but I don't think it has to do anything with the library, as the signature produced in Windows is correct. I think it has to do with the charset encoding but I'm not able to find where the change happens in the string. I added a webservice port that takes a String and returns the output of the java.io getBytes() function, but both deployments on windows and Linux have the same returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that how the new line is handled differently between Windows and Linux; in Windows the new line adds carriage return and line feed while in Linux it adds only Line feed.

The code that I'm working on requires the XML to be formatted with new line and two indentation spaces between the parent tag and its child tags, I was using the following code inside my "convertNode2String" method in the Utils Class:

```
    if (indent){
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    }
```

The previous code adds 0x0D0A at each new line in Windows while in Linux it adds 0x0A at each new line. That makes it obvious why the signature produced is different in Windows than in Linux.

Since the entity that will consume the webservice uses Windows as their operating system of choice, the solution to this problem is to change the new line in the Linux environment from LF only to CRLF when the method is called, we can do this by using [java.lang.System.setProperty(String key, String value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) method for the "line.separator" property then return it back to its original status at the end of the method.

To make it not specific to a certain OS or if the default is not LF only we should save the current "line.separator" value using the "getProperty" method.

```
    String defaultSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String WindowsSeparator = "\r\n";
    System.setProperty("line.separator", WindowsSeparator);
```

And after the formatting of the XML is done:

```
    System.setProperty("line.separator", defaultSeparator);
```

Hope someone finds this useful.